# SQLite3::ConstraintException: xxxxx.created_at may not be NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a resque job that creates an artist and associates it with a user. User has_and_belongs_to_many :artists, and Artist has_and_belongs_to_many :users.

```
def self.perform(itunes_id, user_id=nil)
  artist = Artist.find_by_itunes_id(itunes_id) || lookup_and_create_artist(itunes_id)
  if user_id && user = User.find(user_id)
    user.artists << artist
    user.save!
  end
end
```

`user.artists << artist` raises this exception:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: artists_users.created_at may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "artists_users" ("artist_id", "user_id")
```

I have also seen the creation of an artists_genres (Artist and Genre have a reciprocal HABTM relationship as well)

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: artists_genres.created_at may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "artists_genres" ("artist_id", "genre_id")
```

Comment: You seem to have created timestamp columns for your join table. Are you sure you really need them?

Comment: @ChuckE Isn't that the default when generating migrations? Not to indicate their necessity in this case.

Comment: I don't think so, most of the examples and tutorials ignore the timestamps for the join table. But the main thing there is the constraint. You timestamps are not only set, there is a null => false constraint set in the migration. Remove either the constraint or the timestamps and you should do fine.

Comment: ended up answering my own question. There are numerous Rails Issues opened on Github about this shenanigans. Basically they don't plan on supporting automatic updating of timestamps on join tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is purposeful in Rails, but has been raised in numerous issues:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7732
- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7735
- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4653
- https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/4682

HABTM relationships don't automatically set timestamps so I can either remove them or use a `has_many :artists, :through => :artists_genres` relationship

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your timestamps are not set correctly.

If you wanted to band-aid your way out of it, redefine those two fields as `NULL`able (instead of `NOT NULL`).

The problem *usually* occurs when the app is mis-configured.

Make sure that

```
config.active_record.record_timestamps = true
```

If it is false, then the timestamps will not be set and you'll get the constraint error you're seeing.

Comment: This is already the case, but no those should never be NULL so I'd rather fix the cause

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your migration does not set the timestamp fields correctly. This is what it should  look like:

```
create_table :artists_users, :id => false do |t|
  t.references :artist
  t.references :user
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :artists_genres, :id => false do |t|
  t.references :artist
  t.references :genre
  t.timestamps
end
```