# How to use a many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a many to many relationship between businesses and categories

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :businesses
end
```

How would I create a business with 2 associated categories?

```
cat1 = Category.create(name: 'cat1')
cat2 = Category.create(name: 'cat2')
biz = Business.create(name: 'biz1'....
```

Comment: `biz = Business.create(..)`, `biz.categories << [cat1, cat2]`

Comment: If I try that I get ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: businesses_categories.created_at may not be NULL

Comment: You haven't setup your join table correctly. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464299/sqlite3constraintexception-xxxxx-created-at-may-not-be-null

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), like this:

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :businesses_categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :businesses
end

class BusinessesCategories < ActiveRecord::Base
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
end
```

You'd then be able to create your form like this:

```
<%= form_for @business do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :businesses_categories do |b| %>
         <%= b.fields_for :categories do |c| %>
             <%= c.text_field :cat %>
         <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

To do this, you'd have to build the category objects in the controller:

```
#app/controllers/businesses_controller.rb
def new
    @business = Business.new
    2.times do { @business.categories.build }
end
```

---

Or you'd have to call from a separate function to input the category data into their own table with the `business_id` set to the one you want

Answer (score -1):

### **This is the Anothe way of specifying the many to many relationship**

class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :business_categories
     has_many :categories, through: :business_categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :business_categories
     has_many :businesses, through: :business_categories
end

class Business_category < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :categories
     belongs_to :businesses
end

see the link below:: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html